# Disadvantage of redirecting to error page on javascript disabled

Tags: redirect, error-handling, noscript, javascript

I searched on the web and I didn't find any website using this technique. When javascript is disabled or doesn't supported by the browser, all those website are showing small boxes of error above their main content while no one is using redirecting to error page technique. I am using following code in my site to do this

```
<noscript>
Javascript is disabled.
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.wrangle.in/jserror.aspx"> 
</noscript>
```

But as my research resulted in less usage of this feature on www, so I want to know is there any disadvantage of this technique due to which these websites are not using this?

Comment: I don't think `meta` can be present inside a `noscript` tag. Have you actually tried out?

Comment: ya I tried its working fine...

Comment: One disadvantage of having 0; is you break the back button. I suggest you tell the user they are being redirected and give them 3 seconds to be able to click the back button if they end up on you page

Comment: @mplungjan can you explain me in some detail?

Comment: @mplungjan is right. nothing is more annoying than a webpage that does not give you time to press back.

Comment: If I come to you page and you redirect me with 0 seconds delay, I cannot use my back button to go to the page BEFORE your page. Unless I know to right-click the button and select the previous page, I will keep ending up on your JS error page. Hence I would show a message with a link to allow the person to go to the page or some other page themselves, with a 5-10 second timeout

Comment: but if I don't want to show my website to the user without enabling JS, then this way is better, no?